# Obtaining specialized method bodies from ClassTemplateSpecializationDecl?

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++

When dumping the methods if an instantiated template, I'm seeing the method body:

```
CXXConstructorDecl 0x72ecf50 <./image/operators.h:52:3> col:3 used Sawtooth 'void (unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned int)'
|-ParmVarDecl 0x72ecc90 <col:12, col:14> col:14 start 'unsigned char':'unsigned char'
|-ParmVarDecl 0x72ecd00 <col:21, col:23> col:23 end 'unsigned char':'unsigned char'
|-ParmVarDecl 0x72ecd70 <col:28, col:30> col:30 step 'unsigned char':'unsigned char'
`-ParmVarDecl 0x72ecdd0 <col:36, col:45> col:45 interval 'unsigned int'
```

Is there a way to obtain the specialized body?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue; My `ASTConsumer` was doing its thing in `HandleTopLevelDecl` which is apparently a BAD thing to do.  You need to do your processing from `HandleTranslationUnit`.  I didn't dig into the source, but I would assume the former must get called at an earlier stage and the later is called when front-end processing is complete.